# Change resolution for a video on Chrome using Console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

is it possible to change the resolution of an embedded video via console? Previously, I happened to find a pretty cool trick to speed up a video (even exceeding the default speed options) just by typing this command on console `document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 3.0;`. I wonder is there any similar trick for video resolution. My specific case is that I am doing online learning and want to have the videos to be of higher resolution. These videos are youtube videos that offer multiple options for resolution (on youtube) but the webpage which I learn somehow doesn't show the button for personal customization. I am a non-tech person so step-by-step guidance would be very appreciated.

[Image of Edx Video: Always default at HD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFIu7.png)

[Edx webpage links to the above image: Require account and sign in to view](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+6.431x+1T2020/courseware/Unit_5_Continuous_random_variables/sequential_Solved_problemsxxx/)

[Link to youtube video: offer multiple quality setting](https://youtu.be/1872CEK5RqY)

Comment: by resolution you mean quality, not size right?  If that's the case, they usually have different quality videos that are uploaded, not 1 video.

Comment: Yes, it's the quality. I would like to adjust the quality of the video. Like, some videos always default at highest quality (no other options or buttons), I want to decrease down to 480 for faster loading, (or do the opposite, increase the quality for the default low quality videos)

Comment: right, for that they literally have different videos at different qualities - so if you reduce the quality, you're not getting the same video any more, your're actually getting a different video at the adjusted quality.  So this can't be done with JS.  You would make a drop-down and if the user clicked on a lower res video, the uri would point to a lower res video that you had previously uploaded.  make sense?

Comment: So it is hopeless then? I have to write some long code in JS or something right? I kinda disappointed since it's quite easy with the video speed though. Btw, I have edited my post, adding some links and a screenshot.

Comment: not hopeless - but it is not a standard feature like .playbackRate or .volume or something.  Let's say you want 4 quality options? YOU need to upload 4 different videos each set to the quality you want.  Then on the video player, you need to point each of those quality options at where you uploaded the video.  If you don't know how to do all of that, then your best bet is to upload your stuff to youtube, then embed the youtube player.

Answer (score 0):

Try right click on the video and see if you can get the URL of the video, then, watch it in YouTube.

Other options could be (*since you're using the Google Chrome console*):

- Right click on the YouTube video > Inspect element and see the source code: there, for sure the YouTube video link
- Or, (*in the webpage you're inspecting*) press `ctrl + u` (*for get in a separated tab in your browser*), then press `ctrl + f` and search for `YouTube`.

Any of the previous options will allow you to get the YouTube video in a webpage and you just copy and paste the obtained URL and watch directly the video on YouTube.

Comment: Well, I could go for the link but I am hoping for other solutions. It's quite annoying to jump between tabs, plus it's would be much nicer if I could then do trick like that for non-youtube videos on some webpage.

Comment: @user12021 if is for non-YouTube videos, it would help you [edit] your question and add the webpage you're talking about. I'm not sure if those videos are directly in the `<video>` HTML5 tag or other elements...can you add a link example of the YouTube video as is in the webpage?

Comment: Please see my edited post. I actually learn on Edx platform, the default setting is in HD (no other option) say I want to have it adjustable to 480p as on Youtube. I added the link though it's quite annoying since you need to create an account then sign in for the course to be able to see it, so I also post my screenshot too.